# PHP codesniffer - how to teach it to ignore white space?

Tags: php, coding-style

I am using PHP CodeSniffer to check if my code complies to Zend standards.
80 chars per line is one of them. But I prefer to indent line with white spaces
and sniffer treat short lines with line indentations as long lines.

Is there a way to teach it to ignore whitespace identations?
Or it makes sense and the farther my line is indented, the shorter it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this makes perfect sense to keep a line to 80 characters, no matter how many indentations you have.

Answer (score 3):

This setting should be in the ruleset.xml withint the Standards/Zend directory, for example /usr/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer/Standards/Zend/ruleset.xml

Here will be a block like the following;

```
 <rule ref="Generic.Files.LineLength">
   <properties>
     <property name="lineLimit" value="80"/>
     <property name="absoluteLineLimit" value="120"/>
   </properties>
 </rule>
```

Update the 'lineLimit' and 'absoluteLineLimit' to your liking.
The difference between these two settings is lines exceeding the 'absoluteLineLimit' will trigger errors, while 'lineLimit' only causes warnings.

Indentation is part of a lines length. By default it is impossible to ignore these, though you could write your own *sniff* if you really want this. But I would advice against it, because it invalidates the whole point of having maximum lengths.

Answer (score 0):

per [codesniffer:docs](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.config-options.php)

```
When the tab width is set by default, the replacement of tabs with spaces 
can be disabled for a single script run by setting the tab width to zero.

Disabling the replacement of tabs with spaces

$ phpcs --tab-width=0 /path/to/code
```

This of course won't help you condensing down to 80 col if your tabs/spacing is causing this to happen.

Comment: so the answer is yes, the more indented the line is, the shorter it must be.